# Konsole doesn't load yarn when its opened with --new-tab flag

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal, kde-plasma, konsole

I'm using Kubuntu with Konsole, and I find myself running the same set of commands daily in a terminal with multiple tabs. These commands include rails s, sidekiq, yarn watch --build, and others. I'm attempting to automate this small task using Konsole's command-line interface.

Here's the command I'm using:

```
konsole --new-tab --hold --workdir=$PWD -e 'yarn build --watch'
```

And encounter the next warning/error

```
Warning: Could not find 'yarn', starting '/usr/bin/zsh' instead. Please check your profile settings.
/usr/bin/zsh: can't open input file: build
```

However, if I run the command without the --new-tab flag like this:

```
konsole --hold --workdir=$PWD -e 'yarn build --watch'
```

It works as intended but open a new window

Do you have any advice on how to solve this issue? Alternatively, is there another way to achieve what I'm looking for? I've explored the option of using layouts, but it seems layouts don't preserve the commands. ~Even if you have a better terminal emulator that allows me achieve that~

I tried changing the command to `/usr/bin/zsh -l` (login shell), tried running with bash (same error), looking if something was missing or wrong in zshrc/bashrc config files (though I don't fully understand them)